# Disable input submit button with js in IE & FF doesnt' work

Tags: javascript, button, status

I have a problem, with disabling a input button with javascript in a aspx document at ie.

The js look's like

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function SetButtonStatus(sender, target) 
{
    if (searchinput.value.length < 4) 
    {
        document.getElementById(target).disabled = true;
    }
    else 
    {
        document.getElementById(target).disabled = false;
    }
}
</script>
```

I call the input button with

```
<input name="searchinput" type="text" value="" id="searchinput" onkeyup="SetButtonStatus(this, 'searchsubmit')" />
```

In Chrome everything works fine. If i type more then 4 characters in the inputfield, the button will be enabled. But in IE & FF nothing happens... Why? How could i fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are depending on the non-standard "Create a global variable for every element that has an id" that is supported by Chrome and IE in some rendering modes.

Replace `searchinput` with `sender` (since you have defined `sender` and passed a reference to the element you are interested in already).

Comment: Sorry, but what did u mean with "supported by Chrome and IE in some rendering modes" How did i know about the rendering modes? I thought, i could disable or enable every HTML element with js which contain the attribute. Why a global variable? Every element has a id? Im very new to js...

Comment: With some Doctypes (or no Doctype) some browsers decide that the author [doesn't know what they are doing](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/quirksmode.html) and start emulating ancient browsers. This means more bugs, more inconsistency, and more non-standard junk. Always use Standards mode.

Comment: "Why a global variable?" — About 15 years ago, Microsoft thought it was a good idea. It wasn't.

Answer (score 2):

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function SetButtonStatus(sender, target) 
{
    // use document.getElementById("searchinput") instead of searchinput or in your case can use sender 
    document.getElementById(target).disabled = document.getElementById("searchinput").value.length < 4;
}
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

Why don't you just use jquery it handles all browsers internaly and you don't have to worry about them. Make it like this:

```
<input name="searchinput" type="text" value="" id="searchinput"/>
<input type="button" value="button" disabled="true" id="buttonSearch"/>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>  

<script type="text/javascript">

    $(function(){
      $('#searchinput').keydown(function(e){

        var lenght = 3;

        if(e.keyCode ==8)
        {
            lenght = 5;
        }

         if (searchinput.value.length < lenght) 
          {
            $('#buttonSearch').attr("disabled", true);
          }
          else
          {
           $('#buttonSearch').removeAttr('disabled');
          }

       });

    });
</script>
```